# How do I delete a file in a read-only directory?

Tags: files, permissions, rm

I've got a directory and a file in it, with the directory marked as read-only:

```
$ mkdir directoryname
$ touch directoryname/filename
$ chmod a-w directoryname
```

I cannot delete the file, even if pass the `-f` flag to `rm`:

```
$ rm -f directoryname/filename
rm: cannot remove `directoryname/filename': Permission denied
```

Is there a way to force `rm` to delete this file? Obviously, I could temporarily give `directoryname` write permissions, but I'm looking for a more convenient way.

I believe the underlying `unlink` syscall fails in the same way. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: If it where possible why would we need permissions? you are revoking write permission to the directory which implies delete, therefore you are not allowed to write/delete. You may be looking for a `chmod 755` which will allow you to write/delete but won't allow your group nor others.

Comment: It's possible to delete read-only files with `rm -f`, but not files in read-only directories. I'm just looking for a convenient one-line command, I know why it fails by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
sudo rm directory/filename
```

or:

```
su -c "rm directory/filename"
```

depending on your distro and/or setup.

You are giving yourself a temporary `root` for the duration of the above commands and as `root` is almighty on Unix/Linux you are allowed to do anything.  This contrasts with MS Windows where you can remove access to the administrator account (although there are ways around that).

`SELinux` can help as can various extended attributes tools (such as `chattr`) but in the end, they can be bypassed as `root` can alter the extended attributes and can configure (and even disable) `SELinux`.

Comment: Why does root have extra privileges that even the owner of the directory and file doesn't have?

Comment: That is OK if you are in the sudoers or can be root.

Comment: @Flimm - Root is the admin of the entire system. So ofcourse the root has permissions to do almost anything.  You can Google more information on this.

Comment: @Flimm, Unix was designed in such a way that the **root** user can do anything, unrestricted by the kernel. Only recent additions like the immutable file attribute (see the [`chattr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html) or [`chflags`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chflags&sektion=1) commands) or SELinux can limit **root**'s power.

Comment: On FreeBSD you can increase the [security level](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=init) to 1 so that the system immutable and system append-only flags may not be turned off. Any super-user process can raise the security level, but no process can lower it, so the only way to get back to 0 is by rebooting.

Comment: The same goes for SELinux. It can be configured in such a way, that it's practically impossible to disable it. See for example Russell Coker's [SELinux Play Machines](http://www.coker.com.au/selinux/play.html).

Comment: @CristianCiupitu - that SELinux Play Machine sounds quite impressive.